# Prevent access to files png or pdf directly witouth RBAC sesion

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

I'm using Yii2 and this witget (https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin) for controll to access, and when the user is logged he can see all images and this ok, but I need block all access directly using url from outsite if not logging.

For example 
http:// examplesite.com/web/files/example.jpg

If user is not logged, he should't see the image.

I tried using ".htacces" but I don't found nothing works.

I'm using PHP 7, Apache over linux

Comment: I think, like an option, you can take a look to implement a control action to return your images. And add Access Control behavior to this action.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple way you can check if the user is logged in by implementing this code in **view** file:

```
<div>
     <? if(\Yii::$app->user->isGuest()):?>
         <!--Display image for Guests-->
     <? elseif:>
         <!--Images for users-->
     <? endif; ?>
</div>
```

Another solution, you can use urlManager and controller to check:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(img/.+\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif))$ /index.php/site/img/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way you offer to pass all images through the application. But those that need to be given by logic should be stored in an inaccessible place from the outside or requested by a page through your specific route, for example: images.
All images are in web/img, and they are available directly from Apache, for those images that have logic, use:

```
Url::to(['images/get-images', 'imgPath => 'img/logo.png'])

// urlManager rule 
[
    'pattern'=>'get-img/<imgPath>', 
    'route'=>'images/get-images'
],
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: It was not necessary move all files from folder because I have all my images into a folder on "web/uploads/" just I added this rule.   RedirectMatch 403 ^/lmyproject/web/uploads/.*$   Thanks Serghei Leonenco.

Comment: It was just example of image location.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block images from viewing them by direct link for guest users. If you block images in .htaccess, logged in users will not be able to view them.

You can implement access to images by PHP:
1. Image URL will look like /images/some_hash
2. All requests to /images/* should be captured by the application
3. App checks access in each request
4. If access is granted, app reads an image file and gives it in response (with correct headers). You should implement a mapping between real images and hashes from (1)

Comment: The reason why he need to prevent access to some sort of files or type of files for unregistered users, so they not be able to share this link, even hashed. Link like: 'abc.com/hash123' can still be open by anybody who know it.